# Mixing Spring Data Envers and QueryDSL

Tags: spring-data, querydsl, spring-data-envers

I'm using a global custom repository in my project which extends QueryDslJpaRepository:

```
   public class CustomPagingAndSortingRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID>
    implements CustomPagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {
```

And the interface:

```
   public interface CustomPagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {
```

And then on my configuration I annotate it with:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CustomPagingAndSortingRepositoryImpl.class)
```

All is working fine, but now I was trying to add auditing support to my entities by using spring-data-envers and according to the docs I should use a specific repository factory bean class :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class, repositoryBaseClass = CustomPagingAndSortingRepositoryImpl.class)
```

Now obviously if I do this things won't work because my repositories will now be created through the EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean class and will no longer be of CustomPagingAndSortingRepositoryImpl type.

How can I support something like this? I'm not seeing how since my custom repository need to extend from QueryDslJpaRepository already.

Comment: You might want to watch https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-102 It's getting implemented right now, and might improve the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the relevant part for you is this method of [EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/envers/repository/support/EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.java#L113):

```
@Override
protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
    return EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl.class;
}
```

Here you really want your `CustomPagingAndSortingRepositoryImpl` returned. So I would try the following:

1. extend `EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean` and overwrite `getRepositoryBaseClass` to return your `CustomPagingAndSortingRepositoryImpl`.
2. Make `CustomPagingAndSortingRepositoryImpl` extend [`EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/envers/repository/support/EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl.java).

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work because CustomPagingAndSortingRepositoryImpl is already extending QueryDslJpaRepository so it cannot extend EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl

Comment: implementing all the interfaces implemented by both classes should be sufficient. So extend from one + the missing interface and copy the code from the other implementation (or delegate to an instance of it).

Comment: I was trying to avoid copy pasting code from the other implementations because I don't think that's a good solution (would need to review it every time I update the library to a new version). I guess delegating to a new instance would work, that's what i was trying, but was getting trouble setting the RevisionEntityInformation for the EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl constructor, I don't understand how/when revisionEntityClass is set in EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.